# Непонятный цикл

Tags: c++

Недавно увидел на ревью такой цикл:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sockets_number; ++i) {
   i[sockets].connect(endpoint);
}
```

`sockets` - это массив вида `Socket sockets[sockets_number]`. Объясните, как это работает? Вроде бы должно быть `sockets[i].connect(endpoint)` или я отстал от жизни?

Comment: Язык позволяет менять местами, но не вздумайте так писать в реальной жизни (уволят и будут правы)

Comment: (режим шуток включен) конечно не стоит. Ведь нужно писать хотя бы так `i<:sockets:>.connect(endpoint)` (режим шуток выключен)

Answer (score 1):

К массиву можно обращаться посредством, например: `5[arr]`, это эквивалентно `arr[5]`. Вот ещё примеры:

`(1 + 3)[a]` – то же, что и `a[1 + 3]`

`(a + 1)[2]` – то же, что и `a[3]`

Answer (score 1):

```
arr[idx] ~ *(arr + idx) <-> *(idx + arr) ~ idx[arr]
```

[Стандарт C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf): **6.5.2.1 Array subscripting**

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
>   (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently,apointer to
>   the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer, E1[E2]
>   designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).